# Setting layer identifiable, seachable and removable with Python in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

With PyQGIS, I want to set project layer properties (`Project Menu > Properties > DataSource`) such as *Identifiable*, *Searchable* and *Required* (for *Read Only*, the method is `QgsVectorLayer.setReadOnly()` ([link](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html?highlight=qgsvectorlayer#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.setReadOnly))).

In the [API doc](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProject.html?highlight=qgsproject#qgis.core.QgsProject.nonIdentifiableLayers), for the method `QgsProject.nonIdentifiableLayers()`, it says:

> Deprecated since version since: QGIS 3.4 use `QgsMapLayer.setFlags()` instead

But there is no clear documentation (for me) or example for how to use this new method [`QgsMapLayer.setFlags()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsMapLayer.html?highlight=qgsmaplayer#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.setFlags).

I would like to understand how to use this method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to understand the behavior of the `setFlags` method by see on a vector layer the results of :

```py
vl = iface.activeLayer()
flags = 1
vl.setFlags(QgsMapLayer.LayerFlag(flags))
# result : the layer is identifiable and required
```

I looked at the [Python API doc for QgsMapLayer](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsMapLayer.html?highlight=qgsmaplayer#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.Identifiable), in these attributes and :

- Identifiable = 1 (= 2 power 0)
- Removable = 2 (= 2 power 1)
- Searchable = 4 (= 2 power 2)

If we draw a binary table :

<kbd>Num</kbd><kbd>2 power 2</kbd><kbd>2 power 1</kbd><kbd>2 power 0</kbd>
   <kbd>0</kbd>   
      <kbd>0</kbd>      
      <kbd>0</kbd>      
      <kbd>0</kbd>      

   <kbd>1</kbd>   
      <kbd>0</kbd>      
      <kbd>0</kbd>      
      <kbd>1</kbd>      

   <kbd>2</kbd>   
      <kbd>0</kbd>      
      <kbd>1</kbd>      
      <kbd>0</kbd>      

   <kbd>3</kbd>   
      <kbd>0</kbd>      
      <kbd>1</kbd>      
      <kbd>1</kbd>      

   <kbd>4</kbd>   
      <kbd>1</kbd>      
      <kbd>0</kbd>      
      <kbd>0</kbd>      

   <kbd>5</kbd>   
      <kbd>1</kbd>      
      <kbd>0</kbd>      
      <kbd>1</kbd>      

   <kbd>6</kbd>   
      <kbd>1</kbd>      
      <kbd>1</kbd>      
      <kbd>0</kbd>      

   <kbd>7</kbd>   
      <kbd>1</kbd>      
      <kbd>1</kbd>      
      <kbd>1</kbd>

and a table of project layer settings (DataSource tab) with the result of `vl.setFlags(QgsMapLayer.LayerFlag(Num))`, 1 as *True* and 0 as *False* :

<kbd>Num</kbd><kbd>Searchable</kbd> <kbd>Required</kbd> <kbd>Identifiable</kbd>
   <kbd>0</kbd>   
       <kbd>0</kbd>       
       <kbd>1</kbd>       
       <kbd>0</kbd>       

   <kbd>1</kbd>   
       <kbd>0</kbd>       
       <kbd>1</kbd>       
       <kbd>1</kbd>       

   <kbd>2</kbd>   
       <kbd>0</kbd>       
       <kbd>0</kbd>       
       <kbd>0</kbd>       

   <kbd>3</kbd>   
       <kbd>0</kbd>       
       <kbd>0</kbd>       
       <kbd>1</kbd>       

   <kbd>4</kbd>   
       <kbd>1</kbd>       
       <kbd>1</kbd>       
       <kbd>0</kbd>       

   <kbd>5</kbd>   
       <kbd>1</kbd>       
       <kbd>1</kbd>       
       <kbd>1</kbd>       

   <kbd>6</kbd>   
       <kbd>1</kbd>       
       <kbd>0</kbd>       
       <kbd>0</kbd>       

   <kbd>7</kbd>   
       <kbd>1</kbd>       
       <kbd>0</kbd>       
       <kbd>1</kbd>

- Identifiable behavior equals 2 power 0
- Searchage behavior equals 2 power 2
- but Removable behavior is the inverse of 2 power 1.

... and wait ! **Required** is the inverse of **Removable**.

For set these settings for a layer in a project, the code is :

```py
vl = activeLayer()
identifiable = QgsMapLayer.Identifiable
searchable = QgsMapLayer.Searchable
removable = QgsMapLayer.Removable

# for a non-required and identifiable layer
vl.setFlags(QgsMapLayer.LayerFlag(identifiable + removable))

# for a searchable only layer
vl.setFlags(QgsMapLayer.LayerFlag(searchable + removable))

# for a searchable and required layer
vl.setFlags(QgsMapLayer.LayerFlag(searchable))
```

Or a function :

```py
def layer_settings(vectorLayer, isIdentifiable=True,
    isSearchable=True, isRequired=False):

    flags = 0
    if isIdentifiable:
        flags += QgsMapLayer.Identifiable

    if isSearchable:
        flags += QgsMapLayer.Searchable

    if not isRequired:
        flags += QgsMapLayer.Removable

    vectorLayer.setFlags(QgsMapLayer.LayerFlag(flags))

vl = iface.activeLayer()
# for an identifiable and required layer
layer_settings(vl, True, False, True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, to read the *searchable* and *identifiable*, we can use:

```py
searchable = bool(QgsMapLayer.LayerFlag(layer.flags()) & 4)
identifiable = bool(QgsMapLayer.LayerFlag(layer.flags()) & 1)
print(searchable, identifiable)
```